# React Context value

Tags: reactjs, frontend

This is my user context. I store here all users and some functions.

```
export const UsersContext = createContext([]);

export const UsersProvider = (props) => {
  const [allUserslist, setAllUsersList] = useState([]);

  const handleDeleteUserContext = (cardID) => {
    console.log(allUserslist);
    const userListAfterDeletion = allUserslist.filter((element) =>  element.cardID !== cardID  )
    setAllUsersList(userListAfterDeletion);
  };

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider
      value={[allUserslist, setAllUsersList, handleDeleteUserContext]}
    >
      {props.children}
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Question**
Is there a way to pass value somehow else?

Because I have to call context like this:

`const [allUserslist, setAllUsersList, handleDeleteUser] = useContext(UsersContext);`

and if I add a function in context I have to add it here too. And it's frustrating.
I tried passing value as an object, but it doesn't work.
I tried destructure too:

`const {allUserslist, setAllUsersList, handleDeleteUser} = useContext(UsersContext);`

Comment: Pass it as object instead of an array for sure. You don't need to use destructuring at all, just assign the whole context to a simple variable: `const context = useContext(UsersContext);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract it as object properties you should pass object as context value:

```js
export const UsersContext = createContext({});

export const UsersProvider = (props) => {
  const [allUserslist, setAllUsersList] = useState([]);

  const handleDeleteUserContext = (cardID) => {
    console.log(allUserslist);
    const userListAfterDeletion = allUserslist.filter((element) => element.cardID !== cardID);
    setAllUsersList(userListAfterDeletion);
  };

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={{ allUserslist, setAllUsersList, handleDeleteUserContext }}>
      {props.children}
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then somewhere in a component you can use it like this:

```js
const { allUserslist, setAllUsersList, handleDeleteUser } = useContext(UsersContext);
```